# Put a banner in the correct location

Tags: html, css

My website is basic-mathematics.com

I have a banner on top of my website.It is a 728x90 leaderboard.

I am trying to put another banner next to the existing banner. I am trying to put it on the right of the 728x90

Whenever I paste the code for the banner on the right, the banner on the left goes on top and the banner on the right goes to the bottom of the latter.

In the source code, the code for the banner is located at line 144-148

I will appreciate very much the help I get to put the banner next to it. or on the right side of the existing one.

Comment: Can you post a specific code snippet that is giving you trouble.

Comment: You will get better answers if you provide a small self-contained example, which contains just enough code to demonstrate the problem, without anything extra. Post this code into the question, AND in a JSFiddle (jsfiddle.net). Doing this can be a lot of work, but it's a critical part of the process of troubleshooting your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your source, you should go back to the basics.. (http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

I build a ugly solution which is not the best, perhaps it helps you out. (if i understand the problem.
http://jsfiddle.net/5Rd7C/

```
#header{
    position:absolute;
    width:728px;
    height:90px;
}

#left{
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
}

#right{
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    top:0px;
}
```

Again, this is a ugly way. You should dig in the basics and consider building the site solid. Will make for better times in the future.

Comment: Thank you for your help. That is not though what I am trying to do.I want the banner to stay on top where it is and put another smaller baller next to it on the right.

Comment: You can use the same ugly way with absolute positioning. http://jsfiddle.net/5Rd7C/1/